# Airflow long running job killed after 1 hr but the task is still in running state

Tags: amazon-ecs, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I need a help with a long running dag that keeps on failing after an hour but the task is still in running mode.
I have been using Airflow for the past 6-8 months. I with the help of our infrastructure team has setup Airflow in our company. It’s running on a AWS ECS cluster. The dags sit in an EFS instance with throughput set to provisioned. The logs are written in a s3 bucket.
For the worker aws ecs service we have an autoscaling policy that scales up the cluster at night 1 AM and scales down at 4AM.
It’s running fine for short duration jobs. It also was successful with a long duration job that was writing the results into a redshift table intermittently.
But now I have a job that is looping over a pandas dataframe and updating two dictionaries.
Issue:
It  takes about 4 hrs for the job to finish but at around 1 hr it automatically fails without any error. The task still is in running mode until I manually stop it. And when I try to look at the logs the actual log doesn’t come up It shows

```
[2021-05-04 19:59:18,785] {taskinstance.py:664} INFO - Dependencies not met for <TaskInstance: app-doctor-utilisation.execute 2021-05-04T18:57:10.480384+00:00 [running]>, dependency 'Task Instance State' FAILED: Task is in the 'running' state which is not a valid state for execution. The task must be cleared in order to be run.
[2021-05-04 19:59:18,786] {local_task_job.py:90} INFO - Task is not able to be run
```

Now when I stop the task I can see some of the logs and the following logs at the end.

```
[2021-05-04 20:11:11,785] {helpers.py:325} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 38
[2021-05-04 20:11:11,787] {taskinstance.py:955} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses.
[2021-05-04 20:11:11,959] {helpers.py:291} INFO - Process psutil.Process(pid=38, status='terminated', exitcode=0, started='18:59:13') (38) terminated with exit code 0
[2021-05-04 20:11:11,960] {local_task_job.py:102} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
```

Can someone please help me figure out the issue and if there is any solution for this?

Comment: Abhinandan Bhattacharjee, have you found the cause?